# Parallelization of a CFD python code, mutli-threading and multi-processing, CPU bound, laptop crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Former post below:

*I am trying to run a CFD (Computational Fluid Dynamics) code that works well in sequential, but I want to speed up by parallelizing it. (For thus are interested in, we are computing a heat transfer in 3 dimensions).
More precisely, I have to put in parallel a nested loop of 3 and a 4 one. According to what I learned, my code is CPU bound, so I have to use multiprocessing instead of threading, am I right so far?
I have tried several ways to do so, even threading just in case.
Actually, I couldn't reach the end of the calculation, my laptop has frozen every time I tried, but the code was compiled and executed... I have a Toshiba Satellite with an Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4, 1,0 TB, and 3.7 GiB, on ubuntu 20.04 LTS.*

*First test:*

```py
import multiprocessing as mp 

def iterative(i,j,k):  
     ind = j*(N+2)+i+k*((N+1)*(N+2)+N+2)
     indW = ind-1
     indE = ind+1
     indN = ind + (N+2) 
     indS = ind - (N+2)
     indT = ind + ((N+1)*(N+2)+N+2)
     indB = ind - ((N+1)*(N+2)+N+2)

     if j == 0 and k != 0 and k != N+1:
            T[ind] = T_F
     elif i == N+1 and j != N+1 and k != N+1 and k != 0:
            T[ind] = T_R
     elif i == 0 and j != 0 and k != 0 and k != N+1:
            T[ind] = T_L
     elif i != 0 and j == N+1 and k != 0 and k != N+1:
            T[ind] = T_B
     elif k == N+1:
            T[ind] = T_U
     elif k == 0:
            T[ind] = T_D
     elif i == N and j == N and k == N:
            T[ind] = T[ind] * (1-9*c) + T_R * (2*c) + T[indW]*c + T_B *(2*c) + c*T[indS] + 2*c*T_U + c*T[indB] + s*dt
     elif i == 1 and j == N and k == N: 
            T[ind] = T[ind] * (1-9*c) + T_L * (2*c) + c*T[indE] + 2*c*T_B + c*T[indS] + 2*c*T_U + c*T[indB] + s*dt
     elif i == N and j == N and k == 1:
            T[ind] = T[ind] * (1-9*c) + 2*c*T_R + c*T[indW] + 2*c*T_B  + c*T[indS] + 2*c*T_D + c*T[indT] + s*dt
     elif i == 1 and j == N and k == 1:
            T[ind] = T[ind] * (1-9*c) + 2*c*T_L + c*T[indE] + 2*c*T_B + c*T[indS] + 2*c*T_D + c*T[indT] + s*dt
     elif i != 0 and i != N+1 and j == 1 and k == N:
            T[ind] = T[ind] * (1-8*c) + c*T[indE] + c*T[indW] + c*T[indN] + 2*c*T_F + 2*c*T_U + c*T[indB] + s*dt
   
          ...
          ...

processes = []

for n in range(0,8):
    for i in range(0,N+2):
        for j in range(0,N+2):
            for k in range(0,N+2):
                p = mp.Process(target=iterative,(i,j,k))
                p.start()
                Processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()

              ....
              ....
```

*Why it freezes/ crashed?*

*I also tried to make a ProcessPool like that:*

```py
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

for n in range(0,N+2):
    for i in range(0,N+2):
        for j in range(0,N+2):
            for k in range(0,N+2):
                pool.apply_async(initial,(i,j,k))
    ......
    ......
```

*The same thing, it crashed ...*

*With Thread, it doesn't crash, but the computation takes around 600 seconds against about a minute in sequential... I think it's because my code is CPU bound (and not I/O bound)  and it takes time to set up all the threads ... am I right?
So, I also did that with Process instead of thread, but again, it crashed...
Well, I don't know how to make it worked and not crashed my laptop, which is not a trash a priori.
Can someone help me doing this? Thanks for your time.*

Edit below:

As @Jerôme Richard suggest to me in a comment, I create fewer tasks per cell by increasing the number of operations in one task executed in parallel (increasing the grain size). This improved the speed of computation a lot. Results with computation by multi-threading are good and obtained a little bit faster than sequential but this way is not a real parallelization one. So I want to use multiprocessing with multiple cores to gain maximum time in computation. To reduce the time communication between processes, I thought to compute the 'initial' function in sequential because this work is pretty fast, and only the iterative loop is in parallel. So with all these changes, my laptop did not crash anymore and the computation is faster, but with multiprocessing, it seems that the iterative loop in parallel doesn't work because results are still these of initialization. I tried with and without a process pool, but it returns the same thing. I don't know where is the issue, maybe someone can see it?

Here are parts of my code with changes, first with the process pool:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
       ...
       ...
def iterative(i):   
    for j in range(0,N+2):
        for k in range(0,N+2):   
            ind = j*(N+2)+i+k*((N+1)*(N+2)+N+2)
            indW = ind-1
            indE = ind+1
            indN = ind + (N+2) 
            indS = ind - (N+2)
            indT = ind + ((N+1)*(N+2)+N+2)
            indB = ind - ((N+1)*(N+2)+N+2)

            if j == 0 and k != 0 and k != N+1:
                T[ind] = T_F
            elif i == N+1 and j != N+1 and k != N+1 and k != 0:
                T[ind] = T_R
            elif i == 0 and j != 0 and k != 0 and k != N+1:
                T[ind] = T_L
            elif i != 0 and j == N+1 and k != 0 and k != N+1:
                T[ind] = T_B
            elif k == N+1:
                T[ind] = T_U
            elif k == 0:
                T[ind] = T_D
            elif i == N and j == N and k == N:
                T[ind] = T[ind] * (1-9*c) + T_R * (2*c) + T[indW]*c + T_B *(2*c) + c*T[indS] + 2*c*T_U + c*T[indB] + s*dt
            ...
            ...

pool2 = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

for n in range(0,8): # time iterative loop
    print(n)

    for i in range(0,N+2):
         pool2.apply_async(iterative,[i])
    if n == 7:
        with open("chaleur_para.txt","w") as file:
            for i in range(0,(N+2)**3):
                file.write(str(T[i]) + "\n")
            file.close()
    im = plt.contourf(X,Z,M.T,100,cmap='plasma')
    text = ['t = ' + str(n*dt) + ' s']
    plt.legend(text,loc='upper left')
    ims.append(im.collections)
    if n == 7:
        print("No more iteration.")


pool2.close()
pool2.join()




ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval = 1000, blit=True)
print(f"Exectuion time is {time.time()-t1} seconds.")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.xlim(-0.05,1.05)
plt.ylim(-0.05,1.05)
plt.colorbar(label='Température en °K')
ani.save("Evolution_T_2D.mp4")
plt.show()
```

And without the pool:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

         ...
         ...
Processes = []

for n in range(0,8): # time iterative loop
    print(n)
    for i in range(0,N+2):
        p = mp.Process(target=iterative,args=[i])
        p.start()
        Processes.append(p)

    for p in Processes:
        p.join()
    if n == 7:
        with open("chaleur_para.txt","w") as file:
            for i in range(0,(N+2)**3):
                file.write(str(T[i]) + "\n")
            file.close()
    im = plt.contourf(X,Z,M.T,100,cmap='plasma')
    text = ['t = ' + str(n*dt) + ' s']
    plt.legend(text,loc='upper left')
    ims.append(im.collections)
    if n == 7:
        print("No more iteration.")

       ....
       ....
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/).

Comment: At first glance, it seems you create 1 task per cell which is *insanely inefficient* and would require a lot of memory. If so, consider a *tile-based computation*. Actually, the threading loops confirms this. You create a LOT of threads, probably much more than what you processor can execute. The OS will be saturated and takes all its time to switch between processes which is *very* inefficient and probably much slower than a simple sequential code. OS resources are scarse, use them cleverly and with moderation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @JérômeRichard, so is there another way to use this multiprocessing stuff, or the ProcessPool to make my code run, my laptop doesn't crash, and the parallelization works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Lith , if I can't handle this with classical python ways, I will try this!